# required parameter wrror in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

i create a form in c# windows.form and then create database(MySql).
then i try to save my form information into database with linq every thing is ok but its a error in string that i donot undrstand?
there is my code:

```
var db = new class1DataContext();
db.userssave(txtusername.Text, txtfirstname.Text, txtlastname.Text, txtgender.Text, mobile, txtcountry.Text, txtemail.Text, txtrealestate.Text, Convert.ToInt16(level), txtsocialid.Text, txtdate.Value, txtpassword.Text, txtaddress.Text);
```

And The Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'address' of 'class1DataContext.userssave(int?, string, string, string, string, long?, string, string, string, short?, string, DateTime?, string, string)' Projectname D:\Programs\Projectname Software\Projectname\Projectname\Frmnewuser.cs  53  Active
```

PLease Help Me.

Comment: your method expects a nullable int as first argument but you pass it a string

Comment: `userssave` receives 14 parameters, you sent 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are sending less parameters than required, that is  why address is going as null .

```
var db = new class1DataContext();
db.userssave( ' missing paramater ',txtusername.Text, txtfirstname.Text, txtlastname.Text, txtgender.Text, mobile, txtcountry.Text, txtemail.Text, txtrealestate.Text, Convert.ToInt16(level), txtsocialid.Text, txtdate.Value, txtpassword.Text, txtaddress.Text);
```

here only 13 parameter

```
.userssave(int?, string, string, string, string, long?, string, string, string, short?, string, DateTime?, string, string)
```

method has 14 paramater

Comment: thanks for answer but in my database the first parametr is primary auto fill key and in the database procedures i dont write that in the code.

Comment: @polrealestate can you share more information what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: @polrealestate It doesn't matter what the field is configured to be *in your database* because this is C# code .You can't flag a parameter as "automatically generated" in C#, you provided 13 arguments to a method taking 14 parameters. If you inside this method intend to ignore the first argument you're free to do so but **you still have to pass an argument to it**.

Answer (score 0):

That is my database procedures.

[Picture From database procedures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/360MS.jpg)

but the database Table have another colum (int) but i dont call that in my code and i want to sql fill that automaticly because i set it : int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody; I try this code and the problem solved.

```
var db = new class1DataContext();
db.userssave(null, txtusername.Text, txtfirstname.Text, txtlastname.Text, txtgender.Text, mobile, txtcountry.Text, txtemail.Text, txtrealestate.Text, Convert.ToInt16(level), txtsocialid.Text, txtdate.Value, txtpassword.Text, txtaddress.Text);
```